# Prevent adding slash before hash in Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, url

I want to add the hash in the URL to go to particular section. My code is to reach the customer section in that page

```
<a href="#customer">Customers</a>
```

When I click this link, the URL will be updated like below.

```
http://www.example.com#customer
```

But Angular 7 adds slash / before hash # in the URL after some fraction of seconds  and URL will become like this.

```
http://www.example.com/#customer
```

But the page remains same even though its updating slash.

The issue is When I try to click the Cutomers link again, the URL will be 
http://www.example.com#customer

So URL mismatch will happen here as no slash will be there before hash when I click second time. so it reloads the page

How to prevent adding slash before hash in angular 7

Answer (score 1):

By default the anchor scrolling is not enabled in Angular Router (after v.6.1.0).

You can enable it by importing RouterModule like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
})
```

Doc: https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#anchorScrolling

Your anchor will be the id of the div.

Usage

HTML:

```
<a [routerLink]="['somepath']" fragment="customer">Jump to 'customer' anchor </a>
```

TS:

```
 this.route.fragment.subscribe(f => {
    console.log("f ", f);
    const element = document.querySelector("#" + f)
    if (element) element.scrollIntoView()
  });
```

**Other solutions.**

You can use dynamic scrolling.

`<div #customer>Customers</div>
<button (click)="scrollToElement(customer)">Scroll</button>`.

And in your ts file:

```
scrollToElement(el) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Or
 use ViewChild:

```
 @ViewChild("customer") customerElement: ElementRef;
```

`this.customerElement.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });`

Or use some angular librarie like:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Is there any way to prevent adding slash in config level? Because I have to work on more pages nearly 25+ if I do it in html. Also User will access `http://www.example.com#customer` from different page. In that case, click event wont work.

Comment: If you want to use the same anchor from different pages then place the <div id=customer></div> in the current page and dynamically navigate there. Ex: this.router.navigate(['/path'], {fragment: "customer"}); This will scroll to anchor. Is this  answer for your question? Fragment documentation: https://angular.io/guide/router#fragment